# Google Sheets: Abbreviations to sentences

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace, find

I'm fairly new to google sheets and was wondering if you could write a function to find and replace abbreviations into full sentences? I've tried the substitute and replace function but they only replace the word in the cell the function is located.I need to write a function that will change abbreviations in an entire column. Specifically in my case we will say that coulmn D is my notes. If I type in WOA I would like it to be replaced by "Waiting on approval" and only that abbreviation. Typically the full sentence would be "8/3 estimates submitted, waiting on approval".The next day it might say 8/3 estimates submitted, waiting on approval, 8/4 estimates approved" anyway I can right a function to search for abbreviations and replace them? Thanks [image: example]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 I modifed the question

Comment: based on your image you use the formula in D1... you should use it in row 2 best in E column

Comment: @player0 The issue I'm having is that I don't want it corrected in the cell that the formula is in, I want the cell the abbreviation was typed in to auto fill itself. When I do as you suggested D2 remains WOA and E2 become the full sentence. I want D2 to update from WOA to "waiting on approval" if it is possible?

Comment: Essentially the find and replace function under the edit tab on the toolbar, but without having to open it and manually change it, if that makes since?

Answer (score 1):

### Option 01 - in one formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(
 REGEXREPLACE(D2:D, "WOA", "waiting on approval")))
```

[image]

### Option 02 - input in other cells

Paste this in `E2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(
 REGEXREPLACE(D2:D, $H$3, $H$2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thats pretty close but what I would like is the input to be "WOA" and the output the be the full sentence, I appreciate your effort btw

Comment: The answer does that.... if you put that formula in cell E3 it will find and replace the value in d2 with what's in cells H2/H3?

Comment: I provided a picture to show what I'm attempting to do, I would like the formula to overwrite WOA and change it to "Waiting on approval" in the cell I type WOA. If its not possible then that kind of sucks. I appreciate your efforts none the less! @pgSystemTester

Comment: @Michael Question update seen, check the updated answer.